# How do you rotate a sprite in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I am making a game in Pygame and I want it so every time the sprite jumps it rotates mid-air and lands on its side. A lot like Geometry Dash jumping if you have ever played that. I have some code but it won't rotate.

This is my player class

```
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    
    def __init__(self, color, x, y, width, height):
        super().__init__()
        self.color = color
        self.image = pygame.Surface([width, height])
        self.image.fill(color)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y
```

and this is my code to rotate

```
while running:
    if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            pygame.transform.rotate(player.image, 45)
            isjump = True    
            v = jump_v
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to take the returning value of rotate :

```
player.image = pygame.transform.rotate(player.image, 45)
```

Answer (score 0):

Pygame.transform.rotate doesn't directly affect the image,
instead it makes a copy of it so do

```
player.image = pygame.transform.rotate(player.image,45)
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what is fundamentally different than the other proposed answer.

Comment: Please keep in mind that generally, posting short answers means that those answers are not of super high quality, and that posting a lot of those could impact your use of the site.